# Fetching table partition id in progress

Tags: sql, openedge, progress-db

With the implementation of table partitioning in OpenEdge 11.4: knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P58968

```
select "_index-name"
from PUB."_index" idx,
     PUB."_file" fi
where fi."_file-name" = 'Customer'
  and **idx.rowid** = (select"_file"."_prime-index" from PUB."_file" fs
                       where fs."_file-name"='Customer');
```

How can I change the above query to get the partition details to compare with ROWID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use pro_partn_rowid instead.

```
select "_index-name"
from PUB."_index" idx,
     PUB."_file" fi
where fi."_file-name" = 'Customer'
  and idx.pro_partn_rowid = (select"_file"."_prime-index" from PUB."_file" fs
                       where fs."_file-name"='Customer'); 
_Index-Name
--------------------------------
piSalesCredCountry
```

Comment: @Jjothi Thanks for the reply.  Now  in progress 11.4, after the partitioning of tables, same row id can be there for records stored in two different partitions. is 'pro_partn_rowid' unique accross database?

Comment: It is Unique across a Storage Area. For Partitioned and Multi Tenant tables ROWID cannot be used. We have to use pro_partn_rowid. Rest of the behaviour is same as that of a ROWID. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Jyothi  When I tried to fetch the field details of a table the below query failed. 
SELECT "_Field-Name", "_Data-type" FROM PUB."_Field" WHERE "_file-recid" = ( SELECT PRO_PARTN_ROWID FROM PUB."_file" WHERE "_file-name" = 'Customer')"; i am getting inconsistent types error. what am I missing here? <br> the below query works fine but i think this has to be changed inorder to achieve the uniqueness.SELECT "_Field-Name", "_Data-type" FROM PUB."_Field" WHERE "_file-recid" = ( SELEC ROWID FROM PUB."_file" WHERE "_file-name" = 'Customer')";

Comment: pro_partn_rowid can be used in where clause of a MultiTenant or Partitioned table to fetch data based on the pro_partn_rowid values. For system tables which are not partitioned , i believe rowid should do the job.